# Maximum of a Function using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, function, scipy, max

Function with an x-axis of "k value" (k is a three momentum difference) and an y-axis of cross-section. And need to find the maximum y-value of function (i.e. the maximum cross section value of the function) using scipy.optimize.minimize. Equation is a function of kappa (k and kappa are related) where values of a,b,c,d & e are constants. Drawing the graph on Desmos I know the answer I am looking for which is 245.

But issue lies in the fact that code I have written gives an answer much different than answer I am looking for. Code is written below and equation is at the bottom.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def two_pion_deuteron(k_value):
    
     a, b, c, d, e = 2.855e6, 1.311e1, 2.961e3 , 5.572e0, 1.416e6 
        
     Cross_section = (a*(k_value)**b)/((c-np.exp(d*k_value)**2) + e)
     
     return Cross_section 

Max_cross_section = minimize(lambda x: -two_pion_deuteron(x), 0, method = 'Nelder-Mead')

print(-Max_cross_section.fun)
```

Output is 9.49205479500129e+16 which is very far away from real answer of 245.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to:

```
Max_cross_section = minimize(two_pion_deuteron, 0, method = 'Nelder-Mead')
```

Then you will need to find your correct initial guess (`x0`).

[Source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

Comment: thanks for responding! Changing the line based on your modification I would then need to alter the 0 value in the argument?  Cos I precisely know what x-value corresponds to the max cross section from looking at the graph. (1.457, 245.429) are co-ordinates of for max value.

Comment: @user10705748 I corrected the line based on the documentation of scipy.optimize.minimize, but tbh I am not 100% sure how it internally works. I was reading about it and it seems by given an initial guess, the method will look for the minimum of the function. But not sure what value for initial guess could be the correct one in your case. Besides, there are lots of solvers in the documentation, you are selecting 'Nelder-Mead', but I tried a few more and results change a lot, so you may need to investigate which one is the best one for your function.  I added the link to the source

Comment: I see, will take a look and try other methods. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that this function has a maximum? It clearly has a singularity at `np.exp(d*k_value)**2 == c+e`:

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 3, 1000)
plt.plot(x, two_pion_deuteron(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. I just realised I used exp for the argument in denominator instead of "e^" so my graph showed a peak.